# Is there a general way to have a polynomial in two variables over C (a plane curve) be irreducible?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Is there a general way to have a plane curve be irreducible? If the curve $C \in \mathbb{C} [x,y]$, would it be sufficient for it to factor into linear terms? What about if I have an equation of  the form $(a_1x+b_1y)^r$ and I want to add a non-constant term to make it irreducible over \mathbb{C}.

Comment: Apparebtly yes, but each factor will correspond, then, to a irreducible component.

Comment: It may not factor into linear terms, but it will be reducible if it factors into terms of lower degree. These may not be linear!

Comment: So if I have f(x,y)=x^r, where r is some integer, I want to add something so that this becomes irreducible. What are my options (other than a constant)?